# How to retrieve Django form object inside html to use AJAX later on

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-templates

I know how to save the form in Django using AJAX, but don't know how to retrieve the form object from Django and inject the form inside HTML.

I need to retrieve the form data through 
`return HttpResponse(jhjson, {'content_type' : 'application/json'})` 
instead of 
`return render(request, 'task/mobileInventory.html', {'form': form})`

View.py

```
def get_try(request, sid):
    print (sid)
    member = get_object_or_404(TaskMaster, pk=sid)
    form = CreateTaskMaster(instance=member)
    return render(request, 'task/mobileInventory.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking.  Are you wondering how to send data from a form using an ajax request instead of passing it with a form, or are you wanting to know how to receive the request, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: i want to know to get form data from django to ajax

Comment: do you mean, how to get JSON data from django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Creating Django Form Objects

First, you need to create a Django Form object.

```
from django import forms

class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(label='Some Field', max_length=100)
```

### Rendering Django Forms

After creating a form object, you can render it inside HTML as follows.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def form_view(request):
    # import your form here
    form = SomeForm()
    # you are rendering your form object as some_form inside an html
    return render(request, 'your_html_file', {'some_form': form})
```

### Using Django Forms Inside HTML

Finally, you can inject your form using Django template language's double bracket notation.

```
<form action="your_ajax_call">
    {{ some_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It may sound silly but I am very new to programming I would like to know how we handle the ajax and HTML part

Comment: And also I am getting an error that form cannot be serializable

Comment: I just updated my answer. And also you should read the documentation first. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/